# What makes up the category called "Marks" in NSCharacterSet?

Tags: cocoa, nscharacterset

I am reading up on `NSCharacterSet`. Can anyone tell me (with an example if possible) what characters are in the category "Marks"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCharacterSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000157-CJBCAGIA) have a short description:

> #### nonBaseCharacterSet
>
> Returns a character set containing the characters in the category of Marks.
>
> `+ (id)nonBaseCharacterSet`
>   **Return Value**
>   A character set containing the characters in the category of Marks.
>
> **Discussion**
>   This set is also defined as all legal Unicode characters with a non-spacing priority greater than 0. Informally, this set is the set of all characters used as modifiers of base characters.